# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.stormpath.sdk.schema.Schema at Spring Boot start

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, stormpath

I'm trying to create an Spring Boot application that uses as user management the Stormpath API.

Here is the Gradle dependency block:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

  compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:' + springBootVersion

  compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-devtools', version: springBootVersion

  compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security', version: springBootVersion

  compile group: 'com.stormpath.spring', name: 'stormpath-default-spring-boot-starter', version: stormpathVersion

  compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.10'

  compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:' + springBootVersion

  compile 'org.yaml:snakeyaml'

  compile 'org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.0.0'

  compile 'com.stormpath.sdk:stormpath-sdk-api:1.1.1'

  compile group: 'com.stormpath.sdk', name: 'stormpath-sdk-httpclient', version: '1.1.1'

  testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

  testCompile 'junit:junit'
```

}

And here is the configuration for Stormpath with Spring security enabled:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .apply(stormpath())
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/public").permitAll();
    }
}
```

At this state, using stormpath.client.cacheManager.enabled: false, it gives me:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.stormpath.sdk.servlet.filter.FilterChainManager]: Factory method 'stormpathFilterChainManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/stormpath/sdk/schema/Schema
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
... 71 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/stormpath/sdk/schema/Schema
at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.directory.DefaultDirectory.<clinit>(DefaultDirectory.java:71) ~[stormpath-sdk-impl-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at com.stormpath.sdk.lang.Classes.instantiate(Classes.java:188) ~[stormpath-sdk-api-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.ds.DefaultResourceFactory.instantiate(DefaultResourceFactory.java:65) ~[stormpath-sdk-impl-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.ds.SubtypeDispatchingResourceFactory.instantiate(SubtypeDispatchingResourceFactory.java:80) ~[stormpath-sdk-impl-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.ds.DefaultDataStore.instantiate(DefaultDataStore.java:216) ~[stormpath-sdk-impl-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.ds.DefaultDataStore.getResource(DefaultDataStore.java:249) ~[stormpath-sdk-impl-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.ds.DefaultDataStore.getResource(DefaultDataStore.java:236) ~[stormpath-sdk-impl-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.application.AbstractAccountStoreMapping.getAccountStore(AbstractAccountStoreMapping.java:55) ~[stormpath-sdk-impl-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.application.DefaultApplication.getDefaultAccountStore(DefaultApplication.java:475) ~[stormpath-sdk-impl-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at com.stormpath.sdk.servlet.config.RegisterEnabledPredicate.test(RegisterEnabledPredicate.java:23) ~[stormpath-sdk-servlet-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at com.stormpath.sdk.servlet.config.RegisterEnabledPredicate.test(RegisterEnabledPredicate.java:11) ~[stormpath-sdk-servlet-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at com.stormpath.spring.config.AbstractStormpathWebMvcConfiguration.addRoutes(AbstractStormpathWebMvcConfiguration.java:464) ~[stormpath-spring-webmvc-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at com.stormpath.spring.config.AbstractStormpathWebMvcConfiguration.stormpathFilterChainManager(AbstractStormpathWebMvcConfiguration.java:1357) ~[stormpath-spring-webmvc-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at com.stormpath.spring.boot.autoconfigure.StormpathWebMvcAutoConfiguration.stormpathFilterChainManager(StormpathWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:564) ~[stormpath-webmvc-spring-boot-starter-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at com.stormpath.spring.boot.autoconfigure.StormpathWebMvcAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f4e52d73.CGLIB$stormpathFilterChainManager$71(<generated>) ~[stormpath-webmvc-spring-boot-starter-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at com.stormpath.spring.boot.autoconfigure.StormpathWebMvcAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f4e52d73$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$de2b4e13.invoke(<generated>) ~[stormpath-webmvc-spring-boot-starter-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at com.stormpath.spring.boot.autoconfigure.StormpathWebMvcAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f4e52d73.stormpathFilterChainManager(<generated>) ~[stormpath-webmvc-spring-boot-starter-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
... 72 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.stormpath.sdk.schema.Schema
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
```

If I set the cacheManager.enabled: true the error changes to:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.stormpath.sdk.application.Application]: Factory method 'stormpathApplication' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/stormpath/sdk/account/EmailVerificationStatus
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/stormpath/sdk/account/EmailVerificationStatus
at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.account.DefaultAccount.<clinit>(DefaultAccount.java:68) ~[stormpath-sdk-impl-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.ds.cache.WriteCacheFilter.cache(WriteCacheFilter.java:282) ~[stormpath-sdk-impl-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.ds.cache.WriteCacheFilter.filter(WriteCacheFilter.java:69) ~[stormpath-sdk-impl-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.ds.DefaultFilterChain.filter(DefaultFilterChain.java:52) ~[stormpath-sdk-impl-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.ds.cache.ReadCacheFilter.filter(ReadCacheFilter.java:66) ~[stormpath-sdk-impl-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.ds.DefaultFilterChain.filter(DefaultFilterChain.java:52) ~[stormpath-sdk-impl-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.ds.api.DecryptApiKeySecretFilter.filter(DecryptApiKeySecretFilter.java:63) ~[stormpath-sdk-impl-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.ds.DefaultFilterChain.filter(DefaultFilterChain.java:52) ~[stormpath-sdk-impl-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.ds.EnlistmentFilter.filter(EnlistmentFilter.java:42) ~[stormpath-sdk-impl-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.ds.DefaultFilterChain.filter(DefaultFilterChain.java:52) ~[stormpath-sdk-impl-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.ds.DefaultDataStore.getResourceData(DefaultDataStore.java:333) ~[stormpath-sdk-impl-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.ds.DefaultDataStore.getResource(DefaultDataStore.java:248) ~[stormpath-sdk-impl-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.ds.DefaultDataStore.getResource(DefaultDataStore.java:236) ~[stormpath-sdk-impl-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.client.DefaultClient.getCurrentTenant(DefaultClient.java:111) ~[stormpath-sdk-impl-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at com.stormpath.sdk.impl.client.DefaultClient.getApplications(DefaultClient.java:228) ~[stormpath-sdk-impl-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at com.stormpath.spring.config.AbstractStormpathConfiguration.stormpathApplication(AbstractStormpathConfiguration.java:134) ~[stormpath-spring-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at com.stormpath.spring.boot.autoconfigure.StormpathAutoConfiguration.stormpathApplication(StormpathAutoConfiguration.java:44) ~[stormpath-spring-boot-starter-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at com.stormpath.spring.boot.autoconfigure.StormpathAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2b9aeaeb.CGLIB$stormpathApplication$0(<generated>) ~[stormpath-spring-boot-starter-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at com.stormpath.spring.boot.autoconfigure.StormpathAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2b9aeaeb$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$50955372.invoke(<generated>) ~[stormpath-spring-boot-starter-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at com.stormpath.spring.boot.autoconfigure.StormpathAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2b9aeaeb.stormpathApplication(<generated>) ~[stormpath-spring-boot-starter-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.stormpath.sdk.account.EmailVerificationStatus
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
```

I'm following the tutorial from their official page: [official page](https://docs.stormpath.com/java/spring-boot-web/quickstart.html)

**UPDATE:** The below problem with unknown host is unrelated to this question
">>Also, at random startings, it gives me that api.stormpath.com is an unknown host. But this I think is a separate issue.<<"

Any suggestion is welcomed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `stormpath-sdk-api:1.1.1` and `stormpath-sdk-impl:1.1.4`

[stormpath-sdk-api:1.1.1](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java/tree/stormpath-sdk-root-1.1.1/api/src/main/java/com/stormpath/sdk/account) and [stormpath-sdk-api:1.1.2](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java/tree/stormpath-sdk-root-1.1.2/api/src/main/java/com/stormpath/sdk/account) do not include the missing classes.

You can find the missing classes in 1.1.4.  [EmailVerificationStatus](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java/tree/stormpath-sdk-root-1.1.4/api/src/main/java/com/stormpath/sdk/account) and [Schema](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java/tree/stormpath-sdk-root-1.1.4/api/src/main/java/com/stormpath/sdk/schema)

Use version 1.1.4 for both instead.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how those versions were forgotten there, maybe I was following another tutorial in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

Per the tutorial, use the latest stable `stormpath-default-spring-boot-starter`, which is version `1.1.4` at the time of this writing.  Also, you do not need to include the following dependencies:

```
compile 'com.stormpath.sdk:stormpath-sdk-api'
compile group: 'com.stormpath.sdk', name: 'stormpath-sdk-httpclient'
```

These two are automatically included when you reference the `stormpath-default-spring-boot-starter`.

Comment: + for the clarifications on those two dependencies. I accepted the first answer :)

Comment: Good point.  I thought of adding it, but I decided to focus on the root cause.